# robot_pose_ekf with only odometry information

Tags: navigation, odometry, robot-pose-ekf

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi rossers ;).

My robot delivers only very noisy odometry data. The worst character of that noise are sudden *peaks* of extremely unlikely data and sudden *accelerations*. I thought about using some kind of Bayesian filter to just filter that data based on an expected variance. Can I use the `robot_pose_ekf`-node for that? Of cause, it would not fusion any data. But can it just serve as a basic probabilistic filter? Will it also work on one data source to create a speed hypothesis?

Thanks for your help

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/202089/robot_pose_ekf-with-only-odometry-information/) by [ct2034](https://answers.ros.org/users/12141/ct2034/) on ROS Answers with karma: 862 on 2015-01-29

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

`robot_pose_ekf` is not terribly easy to adapt to new situations or use cases. If you understand how to implement the bayesian filter that you need, it will probably be easier to write and debug your own filter.

You may also want to look into the [robot_localization](http://wiki.ros.org/robot_localization) and [graft](http://wiki.ros.org/graft) packages for more general-purpose kalman filter nodes.

---

Originally posted by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) with karma: 47576 on 2015-01-30

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1